# Way to select when a container's input child has placeholder shown?

Tags: css

I have an input where I'm using these styles to "hide" the input when it's inactive, but to show it when it's focused, or when it's unfocused but there's still text in it:

```css
Input: styled.input`
  width: 0;

  :focus,
  :not(:placeholder-shown) {
    width: 300px;
  }
`
```

This works great. However, the input is inside of a `label` as its container, which uses `focus-within` to change the background and color (color applies to a search icon child of the `label`, which is shown at all times)

```css
Wrapper: styled.label`
  background: ${theme.colors.darkGrey};
  color: ${theme.colors.white};

  :hover,
  :focus-within {
    background: ${theme.colors.white};
    color: ${theme.colors.black};
  }
`,
```

This also works great, *except* in the case where the input is unfocused but isn't empty -- the container has no way of knowing the input isn't empty so it goes back to its unfocused stylings. Since there's no parent selector, I'm thinking I may have to do this with JS. But I'd really like to do it in CSS entirely! Is there a way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This is how I did it. I had a div with class foo. The div had an input in it. I wanted the background color of the foo div to change based on whether the input was showing a placeholder. I used the pseudo-class "has". This will apply the style if the div has a child input showing the placeholder:

```
.foo:has(input:not(:placeholder-shown)) {   background: red; }
```